# RTC MSP430 count mode

Tags: msp430

Using  MSP430F6736A,programming in CCS.

I want to use RTC to count specific time that user will choose. For example 10 minutes. But I don´t know where to start. I was reading user guide+ datasheet, but Idon´t know how to configurate the RTC. Can someone help me which registers needs to be configurated?

Want to use RTC_A in count mode. I cant use ACLK as source cause I´m using it in another function(specific freq). So I must choose SMCLK. How can I configure SMCLK to count seconds?

Comment: If you don't know how the RTC works, why do you want to use it? What is your actual problem?